# How to automate calculations in an Android calculator app using selenium or selendroid

Tags: android, selenium, selendroid

I would like to automate the big calculation matrix[excel] which I have for testing using 'Selenium' in the native calculator app.

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide more information please about what you're wanting to do?

From the information provided all I can suggest is you want to be creating a Selendroid Driver and using it to find and click the relevant elements for your calculation test. Possibly something along these lines (although I can only guess with the current info):

```
WebDriver driver = new SelendroidDriver(*capabilities*)
driver.findElement(By.id("number1Elementinput")).sendkeys("number");
// possibly use a wait method to wait for keys to be sent into input
driver.findElement(By.id("calculateElementId")).click;
```

Unfortunately I have to guess at what you're after, try and provide some more information and I can try and improve my answer (or someone else might provide a better one).

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more information for the question. This question is so broad.

Based on the information provided by you all I can guess is that you want to automate a calculator app testing and the test values are provided in an excel file.

For that I would suggest that first you use `POI` `apache` to read the excel file values and then please if you can go through `Selendroid` documentation http://selendroid.io/setup.html to set up the testing environment. And then you can proceed with writing the testing scripts in the languages that are supported by `Selendroid`. And I hope that you provide more information about your problem and where you are stuck so that an improved answer can be provided.